# How to check SaltStack's SLS files for syntactic correctness during development

Tags: testing, salt-stack, devops

SaltStack is great in deployment automation, but I have to run a full blown integration test every time to check my sls files are just syntactically correct. E.g. if there are duplicated IDs or wrong indentation. Is there a way I can test my sls files in a matter of seconds and without complex environment setup?
I am searching for some kind of linter for sls files.

Comment: have you checked salit-lint? https://github.com/lukaszraczylo/salt-lint

Comment: Project looks dead. And it has only five checks, if I understand correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two possibilities:

```
salt-call --local state.highstate test=True
```

will give you a feedback in a matter of seconds if your states (and other configuration files) are correct including the referenced modules.

An even lighter test is just rendering the SLS:

```
salt-call --local state.show_highstate
```

The `--local` parameter allows you to call salt without contacting the master. Additional parameters on the command line allow you to point the call to a specific directory with the files you want to test. Instead of calling `highstate` you can call a specific state to test/render only this state as described in the state module.

For more information:

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/testing.html

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/cli/salt-call.html

See https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/802 for an ongoing discussion.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, checking through show_sls and show_highstate is so easy to implement, that there is no need in special tool for this task.

Comment: Yes - given you have salt installed in your CI environment somehow. The CI environment doesn't need to be connected to any of your salt masters.